# Quantum Entanglement Simulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, simulations

Suppose there is a digital "quantum entanglement simulator" with a pair generator and two spin detectors, and it

1. Allows to create as many pairs as you want (100 pairs per single click)
2. Allows to measure spin at the detectors in any combination of angles
3. Allows you to set angle combinations randomly, at any time

My understanding is - it must demonstrate below correlations in order to qualify as a successful digital simulator for entanglement -

1. Anti-correlation, when particles of any pairs are measured in same angle, they always have opposite spin
2. Statistical correlation-1 - If you measure numerous particles at a detector, in a specific angle, the outcome must be ~50% up, ~50% down
3. Statistical correlation-2 - If you measure numerous pairs at two detector, in two angles A and B, the correlation (both up, or both down) should be SQUARE of sin((A-B)/2) times the total number of pairs measured at this angle combination.

My question is - Is there any other type of correlation that needs to be implemented?

If so, what is that correlation?

If no other correlation is required then

Follow-up question is - 
I have created an online simulator that is functional, and been tested for all three types of correlations at various angle combinations. May I ask people here to try to find flaws with the statistical correlation exhibited by the simulator.

I am not asking to test the simulator (which I have done myself), I mean to verify the correlations.

FYI - The simulator page is pretty self explanatory.

You can provide dummy information as it does not validate the email address.

Just remember the email address you entered, and password for login purpose.

Here is the **[simulator](http://www.latestemail.com)**   Does not work on mobile devices.

...

Comment: do you know that there are very performant simulations ? 100% cos² and a cross detection rate of 72% with smooth MC algorithms. Experiments reach rarely a few percents of detection ...

Comment: @igael: Where I can try those simulations? Do you mean efficiency when you say performant? What is the efficiency, what kind of computing resources are used.  Simulation I am talking about, is on shared hosting (php/mysql), tested for 120000+ pairs per minute, all correlated as described.

Comment: performant = results are 100% compatible with QM + good cross efficiency. Try my [port javascript of a short version of the algo](http://www.q-crypt.com/animhtml5.html) . It's an old work on an old site ... The complete MC version is heavy to compute but many results are linked.

Comment: @igael: Can you please describe what you mean by cross detection, or cross efficiency? Thx

Comment: Well, my simulation is allowing user to select angles randomly as they wish. I do not draw the graph, user can download the results and verify if it satisfies the sin², 50/50, and anti correlation, which it does as I have tested.

Comment: @igael: Is there real experiment data with two detectors that I can download? I am looking for data and outcome of individual pairs, in sequence the pairs were created and measured, not summary data.

Comment: no, it's just simulations. If you want raw datas, read the last Zeilinger report  ( see in the right column on  arXiv:1511.03190 ). There is a link to a contact to ask for the very raw datas. Cross detection is the product of the efficiency on each arm of the device. It would be fine to do a great numerical  simulation to set bounds to physical experiments. I try to prepare it for october